# Google translate banner - keep visible

Tags: google-translate

Is there a way how can I display top banner (marked red) always visible and never display bottom translate option?

Or opposite way. Show only bottom options with possibility to reset language choice.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement(
            {
                pageLanguage: 'en',
                includedLanguages: 'ar',
                layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
            }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: That's not a programming question, or are you working on that actual service?

Comment: Why it's not programing question? It is part of webiste so how come it's not programin. In your opinion how what kind of question is it?

Comment: Before your edit, it wasn't clear if you were not just a user. That edit was exactly what was missing!